# keep on getting str object has no attribute 'punctuation'

Tags: python

Im trying to make a code that identifies punctuation in a word 
this is all I got up to:

```
word=input('enter a word: ')
punctuation=set(word.punctuation)
for each in word:
   if each==punctuation:
     print('yes')
```

but it keeps on saying 'str' object has no attribute 'punctuation'
how do I solve this???

Answer (score 7):

`str` objects do not have a punctuation attribute. You can instead use [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) to check for any punctuation in your word:

```
import string

# string.punctuation '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

for each in word:
   if each in string.punctuation:
       print('yes')
```